# Getting wrong result while trying to predict using Cubic spline in matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression, spline, cubic-spline

I am quite new to cubic spline and did search found that for my given problem cubic spline would be the best. Based on this website questions related to spline, I have written following codes,

```
 x = [8.91;9.83;9.56;11.74;11.59];
 y = [1310.025;1684.52;1532.052;1997.86;2135.75];
 x_new = [12.05; 13.34;9.82;8.96;8.28];
 y_new = interp1(x,y,x_new,'cubic spline');
plot(x,y,'d')
hold
plot(x_new,y_new)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the training datasets and for a given `x_new` I would like to predict `y_new`. The sample of datasets are given.

The output graph is [image: here]

It would be grateful if any one help me on this regards.

Comment: Why is your result wrong? Including a picture may be useful. Note that `x_new` is not sorted, which will result in some strange connection between the interpolated points, but the interpolation itself is not _wrong_.

Comment: I added the graph have a look

Comment: The only problem I see is that you are extrapolating your data and `x_new` is not sorted, which gives a strange plot when you connect the (unsorted) data points. I don't see any evidence why the interpolation itself is wrong.

Comment: It can be sorted since it coming at given time. So it has to predict the for given x_new what would be the y_new ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying.